Use of "else if" to alternate between lists
I am trying to create a rhandsontable with variables Col1 and Col2.
Col1 has factor levels = c("A", "B").
Col2 has two alternating factor levels = c("a1", "a2") and levels = c("b1", "b2").
The data table I want to create should function under the following conditions:
Condition 1. When "A" from the dropdown list of Col1 is chosen then Col2 should have a dropdown list = c("a1", "a2") to chose among.
Condition 2. When "B" from the dropdown list of Col1 is chosen then Col2 should have a dropdown list = c("b1", "b2") to chose among.
However, the data table is not dynamic as proposed initially since dropdown lists for both variables are not working at all.
Can someone show me what else should be done in my code?
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)

DF <- data.frame(col1 = factor(NA, levels = c(NA, "A", "B"), ordered = TRUE), col2 = as.factor(NA))

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("hot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  hot_data <- reactiveValues(df = DF)  # Initialize with a default data frame

observe({
  if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
    hot_data$df <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
  }

  if (!is.null(hot_data$df) && nrow(hot_data$df) > 0) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(hot_data$df)) {
      if (!is.na(hot_data$df$col1[i]) && hot_data$df$col1[i] == "A") {
        hot_data$df$col2[i] <- factor(NA, levels = c(NA, "a1", "a2"), ordered=TRUE)
      } else if (!is.na(hot_data$df$col1[i]) && hot_data$df$col1[i] == "B") {
        hot_data$df$col2[i] <- factor(NA, levels = c(NA, "b1", "b2"), ordered = TRUE)
      }
    }
  }

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(hot_data$df)
  })
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


This question is similar to: Passing filtered unique values back to a Shiny dropdown box. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It would be easier, imho, to use updateSelectInput rather than rebuilding the UI from scratch after each update.

Then see this instead.

A key issue is that the input$table[1, 1] is not giving you the data from the cell. If you switch to hot_to_r(input$table)[1, 1], then it should work. But I don't have time to test to confirm! I agree with Limey that re-rendering the input is less efficient, and it may be better to use updateSelectInput instead.

dear Limey and  Silentdevildoll, I have checked all your suggestions, but they seem to be applicable in different context rhather than in mine. Besides, I have revised my question and rewritten my script. Any further help and tips are welcome.

I cannot test yet but IMHO the content of the Observe should be a reactive function, my_reactive <- reactive({}) and used in output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({     rhandsontable(my_reactive())   })

Thanks, phili_b. I have tried the way you suggested. observe ({}) replaced by my_reactive <- reactive({}), but the content inside observe({}) left unchanged. At the end I put output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({ rhandsontable(my_reactive()) }) instead of the one which is in my original script. Yet the issue is not  resolved, unfortunately.
